# Unable to see background image when hosted by GitHub Pages

Tags: css, github, twitter-bootstrap-3, background-image, github-pages

I have been trying to correct the path to get my background image to show while hosted on GitHub. I can get it to show when viewing my app from Brackets just not when it's hosted. My CSS is definitely working but I just can't seem to get my image to show. I've been looking at other threads but nothing seems to make a difference. Any help would be appreciated. My website repo https://github.com/Jennp1987/644_final

```css
My CSS...
#backgroundImage {
padding-top: 3%;
padding-bottom: 97%;
background-image: url('https://jennp1987.github.io/644_final/images/pizza_bkground.png');
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;

/*I've also tried this*/
/*#backgroundImage {
    padding-top: 3%;
    padding-bottom: 97%;
    background-image: url('../../../images/pizza_bkground.png'); 
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;


}*/
/*And this*/
/*#backgroundImage {
    padding-top: 3%;
    padding-bottom: 97%;
    background-image: url('../images/pizza_bkground.PNG'); 
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;


}
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

After the tenth try the above code worked!

background-image: url('https://jennp1987.github.io/644_final/images/pizza_bkground.png');

Answer (score 0):

Using your `css` it's actually work well:

```css
#backgroundImage {
  padding-top: 3%;
  padding-bottom: 97%;
  background-image: url('https://jennp1987.github.io/644_final/images/pizza_bkground.png');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="backgroundImage"></div>
```